# Creating Android App

Tags: android, c++, qt

I'm installing qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.2.1.zip for windows and I want to be able to use this to create an Android app using Visual Studio 2010. Am I going about this the right way? Will this version of Qt work for an Android app and is it ok to use Visual Studio 2010 for this kind of thing? I'm coding in C++.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You should download and install:

- Qt 5.x [here](http://qt-project.org/downloads).
- Android SDK (ver. 22+) [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#Other)
- NDK (ver. r9+) [here](http://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/index.html#download)

If you don’t plan to create Android Java apps, then make sure you are downloading ONLY the SDK and not ADT Bundle or Android Studio.

After downloading extract them, open Android SDK (you should have a connection to Internet) and download the desired tools, you have to install at least Android API-13! You also must install Android SDK Platform-tools and Android SDK Build-tools.

Open Qt Creator. Goto Tools->Option->Android settings page and set Android SDK and NDK locations.